# can't import dependency in project

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I have flutter app, and i want add to android dependency to home_widget. `es.antonborri.home_widget:home_widget:1.0.1`

I add this dependency to gradle
`implementation 'es.antonborri.home_widget:home_widget:1.0.1'`

I have import: `import es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetPlugin`
but i have error and android studio give hind: "Add dependency on module 'android.home_widget.main`" but it's not help.

I try clean project.
When i wan't rebuild project i have error:

```
Could not find es.antonborri.home_widget:home_widget:1.0.1.
Required by:
    project :app
Search in build.gradle files
```

But if i click "Search in build.gradle files" android studio find this implementation.

Gradle versions

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Setup your widget using [this codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/flutter-home-screen-widgets#0) so that you have the widget's `.kt` file open in Android Studio
2. Add `import es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetPlugin` to the imports in your widget's `.kt` file
3. In Android Studio, go to File -> Settings and search settings for `auto import` and select the `Editor/General/Auto Import` tab
4. Scroll down and check the box under the Kotlin section for `Add unambiguous imports on the fly`
5. Click `Apply`, then `Ok` in Settings
6. In Android Studio, Build -> Clean Project
7. Close android studio
8. Delete the `/android/.idea` directory (I did this via VSCode)
9. Reopen android studio
10. In Android Studio, Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

FLUTTER ----compile----> Kotlin + Swift. You import whatever dependency inside `Android` folder, and it will ONLY AFFECT `Android` project. You **cannot** import that dependency inside a dart file like `import es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetPlugin`.

Try to use another package of Flutter and add it into `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: I know, i import this dependency in kotlin file, also i have add dependency in pubspec. But it also dont't import required library to android

Comment: how did you import in pubspect.yaml?

Comment: `home_widget: ^0.3.0`